# Is it possible to create a type with two properties having the same name?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_), `Type.GetProperty(string, BindingFlags)` throws `AmbiguousMatchException` when:

> More than one property is found with the specified name and matching
> the specified binding constraints

I'm looking for an example type where the `GetProperty` method would throw because more than one property is found with the same name.  I created an inheritance relationship (`A : B`) where both classes define the same named public property (using the `new` keyword), with `BindingFlags = Public | Instance`, but that doesn't throw.

Comment: Maybe when implementing an interface explicitly and have a similarly named method defined also.

Comment: All great answers!  I want to accept all 3!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, a class can implement multiple indexers, all of which are called `Item`.

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public string this[int firstParameter]
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }

    public string this[string firstParameter, int secondParameter]
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }
}
```

Then you can produce the exception using this:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // This will throw AmbiguousMatchException:
        typeof(Class1).GetProperty("Item", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }
}
```

That will produce the `AmbiguousMatchException` with a single class and the `Public` and `Instance` binding flags.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example using `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` that leads to a name clash between a static and instance property.

```cs
public  class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        public static string Property { get; set; }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = typeof(B);
        var property = type.GetProperty(
            "Property",
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get ambiguous match if you'll play with `BindingFlags`. For example `BindingFlags.IgnoreCase` allows you to get this exception despite not having properties with the same name:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty {get; set;}    
    public int Myproperty {get; set;}
}

typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
```

Also next set up with `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` produces the mentioned error:

```
class MyClass : Base
{
    public new string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class Base
{
    public static string MyProperty {get;set;}
}

typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyProperty", 
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```